# Campo de Formulario - Seleccion Multiple - El PHP Mailer me recoge un solo valores de los varios que selecciona

Tags: html, formularios, phpmailer

quiero consultarle a quien corresponda, algo que debe tener una solución.
Resulta que tengo un formulario con varios campos de texto , otros tantos de selección simple y un campo de selección múltiple. Utilizando select2.

Los datos de los formularios completados me los recopila PHPMailer.
cada campo tiene un valor name="....." , y todo bien, salvo que en el campo de selección múltiple solamente me toma un solo valor de los seleccionados, el último,

El PHP Mailer se lee así

```
    $message .= "<tr><td><strong>|Barcos|</strong> </td><td>" . s trip_tags($params['user-barcos']) . "</td></tr>";
```

EL formulario html

asi

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="js-example-placeholder-multiple form-control" name="user-prestadores" id="user-prestadores" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Puedes comenzar a escribir la que buscas o seleccionar del listado. Es opcional">
<optgroup label="Delta">
<option value="Bote">Bote</option>
<option value="lancha">lancha</option>
<option value="Velero">Velero</option>
<option value="Crucero">Crucero</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le puede servir lo resolví así

$message.= "options:" . (isset($_POST['options'])? implode(", " , array_map("htmlspecialchars" , $_POST['options'])):" not selected ")  ."
" ;// Multimple select box